# Can't get data from database using Phonegap iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, database, cordova, mobile

I am working on a mobile app for iPhone using Phonegap. I am getting data from a database using Ajax. If I run it using Safari, it works fine. But if I use the Phonegap iPhone simulator, then it doesn't show records from the database.

I am using Phonegap version 2.2. Also, I have put * in ExternalHost Array as well.

Please help.

Comment: what do your logs say? Does the request reach the server? Serverside logs? Can you show us any code?